# Hide Html 5 video play button from the screen

Tags: html

I want to hide the video play button which is shown in the screen , is there any way for that ? I am using html5 video player.
I am unable to add image of that here . Please check the link button , there is a image and video button is highlighted by red circle.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/02c4ocr318

Is there any way to complete this ?

Edit: code:

```
<div class="v" id="player">
  <video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" poster="1.png" controls >
    <source src="nrgmom.mp4?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
<!-- <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="youtube.com/embed/nMehBNvN_PM"></iframe>-->; 
</div>
```

Comment: That does not look like the basic implementation of `<video>` in any browser I know. Presumably, therefore, you have a pile of CSS and JavaScript to create the button. We can't tell you how to remove it because we can't see your code.

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery or arrays (since you tagged it as such)?

Comment: <div class="v" id="player">
       <video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" poster="1.png" controls >
  <source src="nrgmom.mp4?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 
</video>
      <!-- <iframe  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nMehBNvN_PM"></iframe>-->
       </div>

Comment: This is the code to add video

Comment: sorry array was taged by mistake but i think jquery is related to this

Comment: i know the css as for video , in html5 we just use video tag .

Comment: If only there were specifiations on HTML video ... http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video

Answer (score 2):

Remove `controls` attribute from `video` element.See this documentation for further information related to [video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh924820(v=vs.85).aspx) element.

[mozilla video element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: It will not remove in native android browser

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend You to use basic html element instead of any jquery/js plugins as it does not show any play overlay by default and works just fine in all browsers with html5 support. U can also customize is via css/js.

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp